# Lower bound algorithm of the Travelling Salesman Problem; does it matter which node we delete?

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

Above is the algorithm I'll be referring to if you didn't know what I meant.

The fact that it states "choose and arbitrary node" implies that no matter what node we choose to delete, we should get the same lower bound for the minimum Hamiltonian cycle of a given graph. However, I've just made up a graph and applied the LBA on it with two different start nodes and I received two differing results for the LB. I'm not sure if I've made a mistake in applying the algorithm (I will put a picture here of my graph when I get home) or if we get different results depending on each node we choose to delete.

Comment: You are correct, different vertices can lead to different lower bounds.  The spirit of the algorithm is that ANY choice of $X$ will give you a lower bound (some of these bounds are just better than others).

Comment: Surely though this is an ineffective algorithm (i.e. surely we want to know with certainty what weight the Hamiltonian cycle w/ the least total weight cannot be lower than?)

Comment: Well, it's NP-Hard to know this with certainty :)  So we're already happy with SOME lower bound.